# How to iterate through and match objects of the same class with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, carousel, addclass, removeclass

I am working on (what should have been) and easy jQuery carousel. Most of the project I have working, the last bit has me scratching my head. StackOverflow has easily 1000+ similar topics, and I have at this point excused many of the unique solutions from those I have read.

The basic skeleton of the carousel is working. Instead of small gray dots for navigation and location, I would like to place the actual image that will show at full scale. My problem is that when I click on this image I do not know how to match, in my case, the classes such that the image will show in the actual carousel itself. I would like to know please, in theory, what steps ought one take to accomplish this.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<section class="main-content">
    <div id="main-car flr">

    <div class="flr btn-right">
        //class needs to be left - objects floated right
        <a href="#" class="left">Right</a>
    </div>

    <div class="car flr">
        <img class="container-car img1 show" 
             src="photo/img1.png">
        <img class="container-car img2" 
             src="photo/img2.png">
        <img class="container-car img3" 
             src="photo/img3.png">
   </div>



       <div class="flr btn-left">
        <a href="#" class="right">Left</a>
      </div>

    <div id="clickme">
        <img id="small-1" class="img1 show" 
             src="photo/img1.png">
        <img id="small-2" class="img2" 
             src="photo/img2.png">
        <img id="small-3" class="img3" 
             src="photo/img3.png">

    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".flr").find("a").click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr("class") == "left") {
      csail("left");
    } else {
      csail("right");
    }
  });

  function csail(direction) {
    //find the img with the class "show"
    var car = $(".car").find(".show");
    var smallImg = $("#clickme").find(".show");

    if (direction == "left") {
      if (car.prev().length) {
        //move the selected class to the previous img in .car
        car.removeClass("show").prev().addClass("show");
        smallImg.removeClass("show").prev().addClass("show");
      } else {
        //there isn't a previous (you're on the first)
        //show the last element in the list.
        car.removeClass("show");
        smallImg.removeClass("show");
        $(".car").find(".container-car:last").addClass("show");
        $("#clickme").find("img:last").addClass("show");
      }
      //endif


    } else { //clicked right
      //move the selected class to the next img in .car
      if (car.next().length) {
        car.removeClass("show").next().addClass("show");
        smallImg.removeClass("show").next().addClass("show");
      } else {
        //there isn't a next div (you're on the last)
        //show the first
        car.removeClass("show");
        smallImg.removeClass("show");
        $(".car").find(".container-car:first").addClass("show");
        $("#clickme").find("img:first").addClass("show");
        //endif
      }
    }
  }


$("#clickme img").click(function(){
    //get src of the img clicked (works)
    var imgClass = $(this).attr("class");
    console.log(imgClass);
    //test
    //get the src of the current img in .car (works)
    var carClass = $(".car img").attr("class");
    console.log(carClass);
    //Remove class show from .car(works)
    $(".car img.show").removeClass("show");
    //add class show to .car img of same class as imgClass

    ???

    });

});
```

Initially I was using the image src with
$("img[src=$'many/different/ways']"). In my attempts
photo/img1.png, img1, img1.png, src=$[' " + var_with_src_ + " ']); (console showed that was == photo/img1.png) did not work.

I decided then to mess with classes. I tried .each() and could get the console to list all the img classes in div.car, but when I said somethings like `$(".car").each(function(){ if( this == imgClass) { this.addClass("show"); } });` also with `$(this).addClass` and the console error was "this.addClass is not a function." in the first case and absolutly nothing in the second, so I assume it ran but nothing I could see with my eyes changed.

In either case, what theoretically should I be looking to do here, such that when a small image is clicked, the carousel shows the large image of the identical class? (OR perhaps better stated: how do I loop through the available classed in the div, match one of them to the variable, and add the class show to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code segment,

```
$(".car").each(function(){ 
    if( this == imgClass) 
    { 
        this.addClass("show"); 
    } 
});
```

should be replaced with

```
$(".car").each(function(){ 
    if( $(this).hasClass(imgClass) ) 
    { 
        $(this).addClass("show"); 
    } 
});
```

In these 'each' callbacks, `this` is a JS object while `$(this)` is a jQuery object.  Both objects represent a DOM element with class `car`.

If you want to control the if statement with imgSrc instead of imgClass,

```
$(".car").each(function(){ 
    if( $(this).attr('src') == imgSrc ) 
    { 
        $(this).addClass("show"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: hasClass! Thank you greatly.
I'd like to point out that when one searches api.jquery for either addClass or removeClass, hasClass is not one of the results that comes up. (for addClass has() is a result...)

Comment: try searching google. They're good with search :) "jquery check if element has class"

Answer (score 0):

> and the console error was "this.addClass is not a function." Perhaps "this" is an array or list of values?

this represent the jquery selection but only the DOM object
you must do $(this) if you wants to use .addClass chain function which is from jQuery

so

```
$(this).addClass('show')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave a the code another go trying both `$(.car).each(function(){ $(this).addClass("show") });` as well as `this` to no avail. 
I can get the console to return the list of img classes with 
`$(.car img).each(function(){  var c = $("this").attr("class"); console.log(c); });`

The real meat of my question is then, How do I loop through that list, find the `img` with `src= imgSrc` and `addClass("show")` to it.

Thanks again ;)